# Convert list in data frame adjusting compound names

Tags: r, list, tidyverse

I have the following hypothetical list

```r
test <- list(a = c("United", "States", "of", "America", "2021", "North", "America"),
             b = c("Canada", "2021", "North", "America"),
             c = c("Morocco", "2021", "Africa"),
             d = c("South", "Africa", "2021", "Africa"),
             e = c("Faroe", "Islands", "2021", "Europe"),
             f = c("Spain", "2021", "Europe"))
```

I would like produce the following tibble:

| country | year | continent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| United States of America | 2021 | North America |
| Canada | 2021 | North America |
| Morocco | 2021 | Africa |
| South Africa | 2021 | Africa |
| Faroe Islands | 2021 | Europe |
| Spain | 2021 | Europe |

I tried to use the `ldply()` function of the `plyr package`. However, my list elements have unequal lengths, because of compound names.

How could I join this data in a tibble with the variables: `country`, `year` and `continent`, for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is to use `rleid` to create a grouping based on the occurence of digits in the `list`, then `paste` the `list` elements and `rbind` them

```
library(data.table)
out <- type.convert(do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(test, function(x)
    tapply(x,  rleid(grepl('\\d+', x)), paste, collapse=' '))), as.is = TRUE)
colnames(out) <- c('country', 'year', 'continent')
row.names(out) <- NULL
```

-output

```
out
#                   country year     continent
#1 United States of America 2021 North America
#2                   Canada 2021 North America
#3                  Morocco 2021        Africa
#4             South Africa 2021        Africa
#5            Faroe Islands 2021        Europe
#6                    Spain 2021        Europe
```

---

Or use a similar option with `rle` from `base R`

```
out <- type.convert(do.call(rbind.data.frame,
    lapply(test, function(x) tapply(x, with(rle(grepl('\\d+', x)), 
 rep(seq_along(values), lengths)), FUN = paste, collapse=' '))), 
      as.is = TRUE)

 colnames(out) <- c('country', 'year', 'continent')
```

Answer (score 3):

In base R you could do:

```
a <- do.call(rbind, lapply(test, function(x) paste(sub("(\\d+)",",\\1,", x), collapse = " ")))

read.csv(text=a, col.names = c("Country","Year","Continent"), h=FALSE)
                    Country Year      Continent
1 United States of America  2021  North America
2                   Canada  2021  North America
3                  Morocco  2021         Africa
4             South Africa  2021         Africa
5            Faroe Islands  2021         Europe
6                    Spain  2021         Europe
```

Answer (score 3):

Slightly less general/efficient than the other solutions here but maybe more transparent?

```r
cfun <- function(x) {
    ## find position of numeric value
    numpos <- grep("^[0-9]+$", x)
    ## combine elements appropriately
    list(country=paste(x[1:(numpos-1)], collapse=" "),
         year=x[numpos],
         continent=paste(x[(numpos+1):length(x)], collapse=" "))
}

purrr::map_dfr(test,cfun)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another base R option

```
type.convert(setNames(
  data.frame(
    do.call(
      rbind,
      lapply(
        test,
        function(v) {
          tapply(v,
            cumsum(c(1, diff(grepl("\\d+", v)) != 0)), paste0,
            collapse = " "
          )
        }
      )
    )
  ), c("Country", "Year", "Continent")
),
as.is = TRUE
)
```

which gives

```
                   Country Year     Continent
a United States of America 2021 North America
b                   Canada 2021 North America
c                  Morocco 2021        Africa
d             South Africa 2021        Africa
e            Faroe Islands 2021        Europe
f                    Spain 2021        Europe
```